# What does Linus mean here in Kernel Coding Style documentation?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm reading the [Linux Kernel Coding Style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/_sources/process/coding-style.txt), where Linus wrote something like this(Chapter 1 Indentation):

> Don’t put multiple statements on a single line unless you have something to hide:
>
> ```
> if (condition) do_this;
>   do_something_everytime;
> ```
>
> ......
>
> Outside of comments, documentation and except in Kconfig, spaces are never
>   used for indentation, and the above example is deliberately broken.

1. What does he mean by `something to hide`? Is it a sarcasm? cuz I don't see any point of coding in such format, not to mention `hide something`.
2. And another question, what does

   > the above example is deliberately broken.

   mean? Does it mean

   > the above example is deliberately breaking this (no space) rule.

Thanks : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Such coding style makes it easy to misinterpret what the code is supposed to do. In the example, due indention and having another statement the same row, one might mistakenly think that `do_something_everytime` is in `if` block and executed only if `condition` is true. Instead the `if` block only contains `do_this` and `do_something_everytime` is always run.

   This kinds of "malicious" indention has caused bugs in software in past, for example a famous bug in Apple's [TLS certificate verification](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) affecting Safari and possibly other Apple software.
2. The example is also breaking no space rule as explicitly stated by explanation.

Comment: But why `unless`? I mean, under no circumstance should a programmer write like that, right? Or is playing 'malicious' tricks like this one of geeks' fun in Linus's age?

Comment: I quite certain its sarcasm; hiding what code does doesn't improve readability which is usually desired and you probably shouldn't be hiding anything in publicly available source code anyways. So yes, you shouldn't under any circumstances write code like that.

Comment: @Cedric It means "unless your intent is actually malicious and you do not want to be spotted easily".